# Writing regular expressions for a Asp.Net website

Tags: asp.net, regex, redirect

We have a lot of duplicate pages on our website and this is of course effecting our Search engine rankings. The duplicate pages are just old pages that are not redirecting. I have figured out how to do the redirect but I will need to do it by writing a regular expression which I'm struggling with.

Examples of the duplicate pages:

`/language-communication/nursery-rhymes/people-puppets-packs/?ev=search`

`/maths-numeracy/dyscalculia/bus-stop/?ev=search`

`/sale/inclusion/harvest-rings/?ev=search`

How would you write a regular expression that would pick the above 3 URLS?

Comment: Explain where is the pattern behind these pages to write a proper regular expression. Without knowing the pattern is impossible.

Comment: /text/text/text/?ev=search(always the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for the above:

```
\/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\/){3}\?ev=search
```